# Bootstrap white space on the right on mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So working on this website and faced with an issue of blank space on the right side of the page on mobile view. I've looked at everything and still cant seem to get rid of it.

I deleted each section of the site hoping to find the area where the issue was (overflowing form something I thought) but it was always there so I don't know what to do.

[link removed] is the site on the dev server.

Im really stumped by this so hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing any padding issue / blank space on that url in Chrome Mac just FYI - Unrelated: Awesome company name.

Comment: I would have to post the entire html and css code then as I'm not sure where the actual issue is within. I deleted each block of code to try narrow it down but the issue persisted so have no idea where the error is. I check for rows being parents of containers etc but couldnt see any problems. The problem is only visible on mobile views also.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is visible only on mobile and almost no way to debug that (well there is a way, kind of a hard way to debug that).

Any long story short ... i suppose one of the page elements is not behaving as it should in mobile view. With this i mean, an element, element X for example is wider then the width of your mobile screen so it creates that white screen issue.

What im gonna propose here is not a 100% solution, is more like a workaround but it will work if the issue is what i supposed:

Apply this css rule on the body tag:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Comment: Give this guy a cookie !!

Comment: I also had to add this to `html` tag - that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Copy Paste your url or paste your code (at the "Check by" dropdown) and you'll see unclosed elements.
Close your elements, I think there is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your help. So I found the issue, As Arber suggested it was an element behaving badly. It was the contents of the carousel overflowing causing whitespace to appear, so I was able to rectify the problem. Thanks again! Tthe validation helps with a few other side issues too.